# My Minecraft forge isn't showing up in a new profile

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft forge isn't showing up as a new profile when I launch the game. I have searched and searched but I could not find a solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually quite simple, but it surprised me. I had to scroll down to the bottom of the "Profiles" list, and select the one titled Forge {version of forge}.

Comment: i tried that but there is no file

Comment: Sorry if you try going to (if your on windows) to start and then looking up forge a pixelated icon of an anvil should show up if you want to try installing it that way. The other option would be to go to skydaz download on of their mods and install it

Comment: they usually auto install from the program they use.

Comment: can i get the link for skydaz for forge???

Comment: I am trying  to get forge for 1.7.10 and it doesn't work also any other version doesn't work niether

Comment: The link is :  https://www.skydaz.com/ , when you get there pick a mod for the version that you want then download it go to it double click it then you should be able to understand form there. If it prompts you to install forge then accept it and it should install a profile just like that.